# Username stored in session changes when $username is used

Tags: php, variables, session

Script 1 sends a username and password as POST to be inserted into a database (separate from the login system itself, instead used in an external program).  Script 2 then does this:

```
$username = escape($_POST["username"]);
$password = escape($_POST["password"]);
```

However, that changes the $_SESSION["username"] to whatever username you enter in the text field on script 1.  I worked around it simply by changing $username to $un, but was wondering why this happened so that I can prevent it later.

Comment: Do you use $username to create your $_SESSION in the first place?  Can we see more code?

Comment: As mentioned you need to elaborate more on the code so we can see the whole effort in place to assess better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing more code, but do you have `register_globals` set to `on` by any chance?

That is definitely not recommended and [removed from php 5.4+](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) but it could cause your problem. You should set it to `off` in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Thanks.  Appears that it was enabled for some reason.  Never had the issue before.  Thanks for you help!